# How to use class templates as function arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, function-templates

I have a class declared along the lines of

```
template<int a, int b>
class C {
public:
    array[a][b];
}
```

and I want to use it as argument in a function like this:

```
bool DoSomeTests(C &c1, C &c2);
```

but when I compile, it tells me 'use of class template requires template argument list.'  I tried

```
template<int a, int b>
bool DoSomeTests(C &c1, C &c2);
```

but I get the same error.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to provide arguments to the class template `C` in the declaration of `DoSomeTests`:

```
template<int a, int b>
bool DoSomeTests(C<a, b> &c1, C<a, b> &c2);
```

Both the class template `C` and your function template `DoSomeTests` take two `int` template parameters but the fact that you want to map them from the function template to `C` can't be inferred by the compiler.

Comment: Thanks, now that I look at it it seems pretty obvious ^^.

Comment: And the reason it can't be inferred is that you could well be meaning:
`bool DoSomeTests(C<a,b>& c1, C<b,a>& c2)`. It might seem stupid but think about matrix/vector multiplication ;)

Comment: You can even use some `enable_if` to typecheck at compile time if the dependancy between the various `a` and `b` is not trivial.